# Trying to register a Stripe customer with a credit card and use the token received to charge the card in Node.js server

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm using the example HTML form to get the Stripe token, providing credit card information.

As a response from Stripe, I get an object containing

- the Stripe token ("tok_173MXoHz........")
- a card object with an ID ("card_173MXoHzqz0X....") which hads a different ID

These are *Posted* to the server and a customer object is created

```
var stripeFormToken = req.body.id;
var cardToken = req.body.cardToken;

stripe.customers.create({
    description: email,
    source: stripeFormToken // obtained with Stripe.js
},
function(err, customer) {
    if(err){
        console.warn(err);
    });
```

and saving the customer ID in a database.

By looking at the dashboard at https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/customers I see that the customer objects are being created but no credit card is added for any of them.

Also when trying to charge a customer by

```
stripe.charges.create({
        amount: 500,
        currency: "cad",
        customer: customer.id, // obtained with Stripe.js
        },
        function(err, charge) {
            if(err){
                console.warn(err);
            }else{
                console.log("successfully charged");
            }
        });
```

but I'm getting back the error:

[Error: Cannot charge a customer that has no active card]
  type: 'StripeCardError',
  stack: 'Error: Cannot charge a customer that has no active card\n    at Error._Error

After extensively looking into the documentation and examples online I wasn't able to solve this.

Comment: There's something wrong with your payment flow. It should go like this: 1. Client-side, use Checkout / Stripe.js to turn card information into a token and send the token back to your server. 2. Server-side, create a customer object using the token, then create a charge using the customer ID. It seems your customer object is created without a token, and thus has no payment sources attached.

Comment: Why does it seem the customer object is created without a token?

as the code shows its created by 

stripe.customers.create({
    description: email,
    source: stripeFormToken 
}

The stripeFromToken is created using the token obtained from the client.

Comment: I verified, and @Ywain you were correct. The token was in fact not being passed as a parameter in creating the customer. Thanks !